# looping in twig and break after three iteration

Tags: twig

I have the following twig code:

```
{% for likeditem in user.getItemLikes() %}
    //iterate over each liked items here
{% endfor %}
```

however I wanted to iterate only the first 3 items of `user.getItemLikes()`

how do I do so?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like you can use the [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter for what you are trying to do:

```
{% for likeditem in user.getItemLikes()|slice(0,3) %}
    //iterate over each liked items here
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The slice parameters are start and length, and it is important to note that start is 0-based, especially if you are using the variable loop.index in your loop, which is 1-based.