# Twig, filter a loop

Tags: symfony, loops, twig

I have a loop in twig :

```
{% for date in dates %}
    <li>{{date}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to use, for this loop, just 5 elements of my array (0-5), after that for a second loop, I need to use next 5 elements (6-11) etc...

How can I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [looping in twig and break after three iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755523/looping-in-twig-and-break-after-three-iteration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html)

```
{% for date in dates|slice(0, 5) %}
    <li>{{date}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

for next loop

```
{% for date in dates|slice(5, 5) %}
    <li>{{date}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter

```
{% for i in dates|slice(start, length) %}
    <li>{{date}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

So, basically, first time you set `start = 0` and `length = 4` (if you want 5 elements you shouldn't iterate from 0 to 5 as count is six), next time 5 to 9 and so on ...