# How to break the loop in twig after certain iteration?

Tags: twig, symfony

I have following code in my twig file

```
{% for item in items %}
    //iterate over each item
    //do your logical stuff
{% endfor %}
```

But just because I've to {{ [dump](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html) }} the structure of the items, I want to break it after 1 iteration.

Comment: so you're a serial "post question and answer yourself" ...it's really sad to see what SO is becoming

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755523/looping-in-twig-and-break-after-three-iteration

Comment: @dagnelies some of the most voted questions on SO where answered by their creators. But it is duplicate so it should be closed.

Comment: @HorstJahns it's not about this particular question. It's about the user's behavior: *all*, or almost all, of the user's questions are like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter comes handy for this purpose:

```
{% for item in items|slice(0, 1) %}
    //iterate over each item
    //do your logical stuff
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: slice also works with objects implementing the Traversable interface.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a break out the loop function. However try this by setting a flag:

```
{% set break = false %}
{% for item in items if not break %}
    // some condition
    {% if item.id == 1 %}
        {% set break = true %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does not work for me.  I get an error, `Unexpected token "name" of value "if" ("end of statement block" expected).`